# Is there any way to create in-app product list via API on Google in-app billing?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I was reading Google In-app billing, and I've seen you need to introduce Products one by one or with a CSV file.

Is there anyway to create them programmatically via API or something like that?

Thanks

Comment: Only the product id (list) is need to be prepared manually. After you have it, you can query product details via API. If you are trying to avoid update the app every time when you add/remove the product ids, I would suggest you app querying product id from your external server.

Comment: do you have some example of that?

Comment: Sorry, after re-read your question, I think I misunderstood it in the first time. You're looking for API to create in-app product in google play developer console, while I mean building in-app product name list in android client side. To the best of my knowledge, the official API (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/) doesn't support create in-app product right now, it can query only.

Comment: Now, this is possible, look in the official documentation:
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/inappproducts/get